# Isolating individual ScalaTest test in IntelliJ debugger without using breakpoints

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

For some reason, if I select an individual ScalaTest test to run in IntelliJ, it doesn't get run (no tests get run, only setup code). Also, breakpoints set in my ScalaTest file don't get hit, so I can't set a breakpoint when the test of interest starts (breakpoints in main code get hit just fine).

I wanted to do that so that I could only enable a log-when-hit breakpoint when the test I'm trying to debug starts, because otherwise the logging is too noisy and slows down the debugging session too much.

How can I work around these two IntelliJ issues?

By default, the IntelliJ console can't read input, so in the default IntelliJ configuration the old "Press any key to continue..." technique won't work.

I tried creating a CountdownLatch, pausing the program and using Evaluate Expression to set the CountdownLatch to 0, but I got the error message "Cannot evaluate: thread is not paused at breakpoint" from IntelliJ.

Comment: How are you selecting individual tests to run? Breakpoints will only be hit if you debug rather than run.

Comment: @Tim I can't actually select individual tests, because when I use `- new utils {` ... `}` rather than `- {` ... `}`, IntelliJ can't see the individual tests inside those blocks. What I can do is attempt to run those blocks by clicking on the green play icon next to them in IntelliJ, but that doesn't actually run anything except the test class setup code, in practice.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up just commenting out all the other tests (this was not as trivial as it sounds, because they are structured hierarchically). However this is not ideal because the test setup code (which is not of interest to me) runs with the log-when-hit breakpoint enabled, so it is noisy and slow.

Comment: You can edit the question, putting more information in answers is really confusing.

Comment: This is a valid solution.

Comment: No, it really isn't, it is a (very obvious) work-around.

Comment: I am the one who asked the question. It is a valid solution for me.

Comment: Yes, it does look suspicious. If it is a genuine question then please put more details in (e.g. sample code) as explained in the guidelines.